# How do I view and edit RAW photos?

Tags: raw

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best free RAW editor/converter on Windows?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/what-is-the-best-free-raw-editor-converter-on-windows)

I want to view and edit pictures that were taken on the setting RAW but don't know how. I dont have adobe or any software so I need to know if there are other ways of doing this please

Comment: Or for Linux: [What tools are available for RAW image processing in Linux?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/471/what-tools-are-available-for-raw-image-processing-in-linux)

Comment: Also helpful: [How do I get started with RAW photography?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/7005/1943)

Answer (score 2):

...use Google? - Although you possibly did this already given you know about Adobe?

So some pointers:
Your camera will have normally come with a RAW editor - for Canon this is Digital Photo Professional.
Other manufacturers have their own systems - Phocus for Hasselblads for example.

Alternatively, you can search for an open source or other RAW converter. One free RAW editor is RAW Therapee - http://rawtherapee.com/ (Though I don't like the highlight results from it).

I am sure a google search for free RAW editors will offer many other alternatives.

Of course as you mention Adobe, ascending by cost:
- Photoshop Elements
- Lightroom
- Photoshop CS

Comment: Free RAW-softwares from most camera makers: http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/1814/17441 which hopefully is kept updated too.