# Lighroom Conflating distinct Lenses - No model information displayed

Tags: lightroom, metadata

I have two distinct models of lenses which are both 50mm f/1.8. I've analyzed example photos from each lens with `exiftool` and confirmed that the relevant information about the lens data is contained in the files. For instance, here is sample output from an example photo taken from each lens:

```
Lens Type: D
Lens: 50mm f/1.8
...
Lens ID Number: 118
...
Lens ID: AF Nikkor 50mm f/1.8D
Lens Spec: 50mm f/1.8 D
```

And the other one:

```
Lens Type: G
Lens: 50mm f/1.8
...
Lens ID Number: 176
...
Lens ID: AF-S Nikkor 50mm f/1.8G
Lens Spec: 50mm f/1.8 G
```

---

My problem is that Lightroom conflates these two lenses into the bin "50.0 mm f/1.8" in the Metadata filter bar at the top:

[image]

The EXIF data distinguishing these two lenses exists in the files, so this must be something to do with Lightroom's reading/display of that data.

Furthermore, looking at [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/76881/prevent-lightroom-from-discarding-lens-model-from-exif) , I can see that Lightroom is capable of displaying the lens model in some situations, as in this screenshot:

[image]

However this is what it looks like for me, with no option to display *Lens Model* or *Lens ID*, only *Lens Setting*:

[image]

I'm using Lightroom 5.7.1, released in 2014 before the bug in the aforementioned question surfaced.

### Update:

Despite the fact that Lightroom doesn't seem to recognise the Lens models in Loupe View, **it can correctly identify the lens models for profile correction purposes**:

[image]

- How do I configure lightroom to display the lens model data (contained in the *Lens ID* field of the EXIF data) in Loupe view?
- How do I filter my photos based on the lens model?

Comment: What are the two lenses?

Comment: @mattdm - (1) AF Nikkor 50mm f1.8 D (2) AF-S Nikkor 50mm f1.8 G. No lens model information is displayed for any of my lenses though, and I want this. Lightroom does seem to be able to apply Lens Profile distortion correction though, which is odd.

Comment: A good step towards answering the question yourself would be to run exiftool on the NEF and get a second opinion on what information it contains.

Comment: Just a note, but not enough to be an answer. exiftool finds the full lens spec for all 3 of my Nikons [eg AF-S Nikkor 50mm f/1.4G] but not my Tamron 70-300, for which it just displays an ID. Even with only an ID, I could in theory take a photo right now, with a known lens & compare [assuming I still have the lens in question]

Comment: @PeterTaylor - Thanks, I've done this. Thankfully, the information still resides within the files. Now it's a mystery to me how to get Lightroom to display this information.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Thanks, this does allow me to see which photos came from which lenses in a pinch. But I'd really like to be able to filter by lenses, and see the lens information in Lightroom!

Comment: Sorry, I can't help on Lightroom itself [I don't like how it ignores data in the raw files so I won't use it.]  Nikon's own ViewNX-i will show the data though, & as an upside, won't mess up the raw ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - what data does it ignore?

Comment: I haven't analysed it, but to my eye, pretty much everything you'd set in the camera. Opening directly in Adobe is a poor experience; going through photo Raw to try get it back to what you thought you'd already got even on the teeny screen. The difference between them can be easily seen by opening the same NEF in Adobe & ViewNX-i. Save a TIF from NX-i & open that in Adobe & you see what you had in NX-i, whereas the one opened directly in Adobe is pale, insipid & noisy. You can recreate it, but why spend the time fiddling with what was already right? Downside is a 30MB NEF becomes a 180MB TIF.

Comment: Seems I'm not the first to notice it... this from way back in 2010 - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/376/nikon-raw-image-processing-in-non-nikon-software?rq=1 & this, more generic - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/how-do-popular-free-raw-editor-converter-compare-to-each-other-on-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is that Lightroom only reads the `Lens` field, and your lenses don't fill it like eg. the XF in your screenshot.

Consider this info from my lens:

```
Lens Info                       : 15-85mm f/?
Lens Model                      : EF-S15-85mm f/3.5-5.6 IS USM
Lens                            : EF-S15-85mm f/3.5-5.6 IS USM
Lens ID                         : Canon EF-S 15-85mm f/3.5-5.6 IS USM
```

The `Lens` field is the only one of these which is part of the EXIF 2.31 specification.

I agree it would be nice to have the `Lens ID` info available, but the only possibility i see is to modify the EXIF data prior to import with exiftool, copying the `ID` to the `Lens` field.

Update: the Lens ID in my example is actually constructed by exiftool, it's not present in the file itself. Running `exiftool -e` (no composites) gives

```
Lens ID                         : 488
```

`exiftool "-Lens<LensID" *.jpg` copies the value from ID to Lens in my example, but a real solution is probably dependent on the individual lens/camera combination and the required result and needs testing, especially with raw files (we don't want to destroy any other EXIF data in the process).

Comment: Excellent observation about the `-e` flag! I find that the `Lens ID` field is missing. But I still have `Lens ID Number: xxx`. This leaves me with a few questions before a complete solution: (1) if I fill the Lens ID field, then will Lightroom read it? Other forums I have read say that Lightroom reads this field, and did not mention the `Lens` field... (2) How do I configure my DSLR/lens to fill this field every time? (3) How do I automatically generate this field for my existing photos (NEFs and JPEGs)?

Comment: The problem is that these fields are all not standardized and LR only reads the Lens field. so (1) no (2) you can't, absent a custom firmware. (3) exiftool can copy data between exif tags. You'd have to experiment what works best for your lenses, i can't really say from here (eg something like: exiftool "-Lens<LensID" *.NEF)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Both my DSLRs and all of my lenses, in all combinations, have all behaved this same way. Maybe it's a Nikon thing. I'd rather not modify the EXIF data manually because I value consistency across old and new photos more than detail (as long as the detailed information is *somewhere* in the metadata). But I appreciate the light you've shed on the situation.

Comment: Another problem with this is automatic lens correction profile selection. I assume that doesn't really work in your situation?

Comment: On the contrary, Lightroom correctly identifies the lens model when I do profile correction.

Comment: @Myridium But it won't filter based on that field.

Answer (score 2):

I've come to a partial solution. It's not very satisfying, but at least I can apply library filters now:

[image]

---

## Here's the **TL;DR**:

**Lightroom cannot filter by lens model. In theory it could, but the developers haven't bothered to implement this.**

My solution was to use the now deprecated *ExifMeta* plugin. I managed to find [a link](http://robcole.smfforfree3.com/index.php/topic,42.0.html) to an old version, 5.9. This plugin works fine with the latest version of Lightroom 5, and reportedly with Lightroom 6 too. Essentially, it allows you to filter by any EXIF field that *exiftool* is able to view. In my case, the *Lens ID* field (a composite field which *exiftool* constructs from the other data) is what contains the lens model information.

This plugin requires a bit of faffing around to get working, and you need to manually choose to read metadata from photos in the library. But at least it works, and should behave consistently.

---

## Details

The heart of the problem is that Lightroom simply doesn't have the capability to filter RAWs by much of the available metadata. The "Lens" filter in Lightroom seems to correspond to the *Lens* field of the EXIF maker notes. For my equipment, this field is filled with the generic description "50mm f/1.8" and not the specific lens model, and so this is all that is displayed.

Investigating the EXIF data, I found that all of the information narrowing down the lens model was contained within the *Maker Notes* section. This section is not standardised, as **ths** says in the comments to their answer.

Here I run a command to check the non-composite EXIF fields outside of the *Maker Notes* which contain the word "Lens". Then I search the *Maker Notes* for (non-composite) fields containing "Lens":

[image]

And now I search for all fields, including composites and in the *Maker Notes*, containing "Lens":

[image]

It appears as though the composite field *Lens ID* is the one which is most suitable for my desired filter. With the *MetaExif* plugin, I'm able to store any such field in Lightroom's Catalog (taking at least an hour to process a catalog of 10,000 photos), and also filter by this field. Doing so with *Lens ID* yields the result shown at the top of this answer.

---

## Drawbacks

- The *ExifMeta* plugin is no longer in development. Who knows the compatibility in even a year's time.
- Photos must be read by selecting them, and choosing *File > Plug-in Extras > Update Selected Photos*
- Reading the data takes a very long time. Over an hour for 10,000 photos.
- *ExifMeta* will not skip reading files which have already been read. The quickest way to find all *Lens ID* information is to filter by *Lens ID*, select everything with *No Value*, and choose to update these photos.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the specific lens information in the EXIF metadata is contained in the "maker notes" section of the EXIF information.

The "maker notes" section of the EXIF information is a place where manufacturers can store non-standardized EXIF fields in whatever format they desire. What information and how it is recorded varies from one manufacturer to the next and often even [varies from one model to the next](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/46806/15871) within the same manufacturer's model lines. This is in contrast to the standardized EXIF fields which are the same across different camera manufacturers and models. Image editors, viewers, and converters don't necessarily display all of the EXIF information contained in an image file. Some don't even display all of the standardized fields.

Just because a specific image viewer doesn't display a specific item from the EXIF info doesn't mean the information is not there in the file. It may mean the info is not there. It may just mean the application is ignoring it.

Some applications will attempt, with varying degrees of success, to interpret and display the information contained in the "maker notes" section. If the application doesn't understand how to translate a specific number/hex code it will either [leave it blank or display the untranslated code](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/45622/15871).

For the most part Adobe products ignore the "maker notes" section of the EXIF information. In fact, if one uses Adobe products to convert or export an image most of the "maker notes" section [will be stripped](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47198/when-raw-files-are-converted-to-dng-are-any-irreversible-demosaicing-happening) from the exported image file.

To the best of my knowledge it is [not possible to filter images in Adobe Lightroom using manufacturer specific fields from the "maker notes" section](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45983/can-i-filter-by-autofocus-in-lightroom) of the EXIF information. Theoretically it should be, but that capability has never been exploited by Adobe. They have consistently stated that they are not interested in "maker notes" information that varies by manufacturer unless they absolutely *have* to access it to enable a core function of the application.

It seems on this case they access only the most generic "Lens" field in the "maker notes" section from Nikon cameras. Probably because it requires the fewest number of possible values (e.g. all 50mm f/1.8 lenses have the same value) to be stored in LR's database. They ignore all of the other descriptive information with regard to sorting capability. They do use the more descriptive tags in the lens correction module because the *have to* for it to work correctly.

Comment: Please see my edit. Lightroom is capable of extracting the lens model information from the existing metadata: it correctly identifies the lens model in the Profile Corrections tool.

Comment: @Myridium Please read the answer again carefully. "For the *most part*...", "... *most of* the 'maker notes' section..."

Comment: Alright, I understand now. The capability to detect the lens model is there, so I wonder if there's a Lightroom plugin I can use to extend the filtering capabilities...

Comment: According to *exiftool*, the *Lens* field **is in the Maker Notes**. Lightroom can filter by this field.

Comment: Theoretically it can, but that capability has never been exploited by Adobe. They have consistently stated that they are not interested in "maker note" information that varies by manufacturer unless they absolutely *have* to access it to enable a core function of the application.

Comment: No, I'm saying it can and does. When I filter by "Lens" in Lightroom, without any plugins, it *seems* as though it's looking at the *Lens* field in the Maker Notes section of the EXIF data. Although it is possible that it looks at the aperture and focal length and produces exactly the same output.

Comment: Huh. **ths** says that *Lens* is part of the EXIF specification, but *exiftool* tells me it's in the Maker Notes. Well I'm not sure what's going on. What I find most puzzling is that Lightroom already has the algorithms in place to determine a lens model, since when I do profile corrections it tells me in plain text what the model of the lens is, exactly how it ought to be formatted. This seems like 90% of the work already done. To add a filter for this information shouldn't be too difficult, but I don't know the technical details of course.

Comment: The Standardized fields are *exactly* the same across manufacturers. The hex code for f/5.6 in the "Aperture Value" field is the same whether it is a Canon, Nikon, Pentax, or Fisher-Price. If the camera's metadata is EXIF compliant then the code for f/5.6 is the standardized value. In the "maker notes" section, each line number and value are completely up to the camera maker. Third party applications such as EXIF tool have to gather enough data from enough users to figure out what each line describes and what the value for that line means. Neither the tags nor the codes are standardized.

Comment: I modified the "Nikon:Lens" tag which I have double and triple checked resides in the Maker Notes (according to *exiftool*). After modifying this tag, **vanilla Lightroom read this change from the Maker Notes**. See [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/wTETmVN.png).

Comment: The only non-Maker-Notes field which contains this ridiculous "10,000mm f/0.1" information is *Lens Spec*. However, this is a composite field produced by *exiftool*, and not contained in the photo itself! Furthermore, Lightroom's "Lens" description of photos do not match this *Lens Spec* tag. My conclusion is that Lightroom is reading straight from the Maker Notes.

Comment: OK. So it is reading one line from the "maker notes" while ignoring all of the other lens info in the "m.n." section. Unfortunately for you, Adobe chose the easiest one to use (fewer different possible values) instead of the most descriptive one. Which kind of proves the point: Adobe's code deals with "m.n." info as little has they possibly have to.

Comment: Yep, you seem to right about that. A shame. I find Lightroom unrivaled in its combined archival and editing capabilities, without the bloat of having to own/use Photoshop.

Comment: I don't know about Nikon's raw conversion software, but I find I have much finer control over color and other response curve related adjustments with Canon's *Digital Photo Professional*. What *DPP* lacks is any sort of non-global adjustments and keyword tagging ability while importing/editing images.